# how to compare two multidimensional arrays

Tags: c

I have two multi-dimension arrays

```
num[line][col] = {
        { '\0', '1', '\0', '\0', '\0' },
        { '\0', '\0', '\0', '3', '\0'  },
        };  
solution[line][col] = {
        { '5', '1', '3', '4', '2' },
        { '4', '2', '5', '3', '1'  },};
```

1. How do I write in num?
   2.How do I compare num and solution?
   Thank you so much

Comment: Use `memcmp`...

Comment: With [`memcmp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyaebf12.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `memcmp` to compare `num` and `solution`:

```
char num[line][col] = {
    { '\0', '1', '\0', '\0', '\0' },
    { '\0', '\0', '\0', '3', '\0'  },
    };  
char solution[line][col] = {
    { '5', '1', '3', '4', '2' },
    { '4', '2', '5', '3', '1'  }, };

int main(void)
{
    printf("Comparing num[][] to solution[][]...\n");
    int result = memcmp(num, solution, 10);

    if (result != 0)
        printf("Not equal.\n");
    else
        printf("Equal.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't positive about what to put as the 3rd argument in `memcmp`. If 10 is wrong, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Down Voter please stop acting like a coward and Explain your reasons.

Comment: You know, I don't mind the downvote (as I'm not a rep-junkie), but I don't understand what's wrong with my solution. It answers the question, it's clear and concise, and it uses proper programming technique. Explain, please.

Comment: `as I'm not a rep-junkie` hmmm.... then you shouldn't have answered this in the first place. BTW: don't hardcode `10` - `sizeof` is much better.

Comment: @4386427 Exactly my thoughts, but I figured I'd rather hardcode it than use `sizeof` incorrectly. How could I use it in this instance?

Comment: You shouldn't have answered in the first place. However, if you do, you better make a perfect one. Oh, BTW - upvoting each other answers will sooner or later get you in to trouble.

Comment: @4386427 I did not ask the other user to upvote my answer. I simply noticed that his answer was a valid, good response, and upvoted it. Whether or not he returned the vote was 100% his choice and doing, and I did not vote his in hopes of getting reputation.

Comment: @4386427 I really *don't* care so much about the reputation. I don't *mind* the points, but they're not why I'm here. I simply enjoy sharing my knowledge with the rest of the community.

Comment: @4386427 If it makes this much of a difference in your mind, I'll edit the answer and request that Michi reverses his vote.

Comment: I don't care what this particular answer is. I care about learning you not to answer this kind of questions. SO is not a "write my code" service.

Comment: @4386427 So punish good users for answering bad questions? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes - exactly. Don't answer questions which shows not effort from OP at all. That is not welcome at SO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130052/discussion-between-md-xf-and-4386427).

Comment: @4386427 This means that [This Question shows a lot of effort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c) ? At least the OP showed 7 lines of Code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I'll doit like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define line 2
#define col 5

int main(void){
int num[line][col] = {
        { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' },
        { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' },
    };

int solution[line][col] = {
        { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' },
        { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' },
    };


    for (size_t i = 0; i < line; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < col; ++j)
        {
            if (num[i][j] != solution[i][j])
            {
                printf("Not equal\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("are equal\n");
}
```

Output:

```
are equal
```

Comment: Down Voter please explain

Comment: Yeah, mine was immediately downvoted too.

Comment: @MDXF Get used you will see this things here.

Comment: Oh, I'm used to it. This has happened before.

Comment: I don't mind the reps, I just enjoy helping people and sharing my programming experience. But the downvote didn't make any sense.